# Error: [8] PDO::__construct(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I keep randomly getting following error:

```
Error: [8] PDO::__construct(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
```

in /var/www/test/includes/classes/class.Database.php on line 33

All was fine till I upgraded Maria DB to 10.2.xx
server set up is:

```
PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:51:52) ( NTS )
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

I tried to increase `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` I also enabled `pdo_mysql` but doesn't seems made any difference.
Does anyone knows where can be a problem?
I would suspect upgrade of Maria DB from 10.1.xx to 10.2.xx since before upgrade I haven't seen such error, even tho I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to Debian 9.

```
public function __construct($host, $user,$pass, $dbname, $charset, $prefix){
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
    $this->charset = $charset;
    $this->prefix = $prefix;

    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset='.$this->charset;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options); //this is line 33
    }
    // Catch and log all errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the actual [mcve] of the PHP side of things? I suspect the connection pool is full, meaning you probably use persistent connections. might not wanna do that as in my honest opinion it creates more issues in most cases than it solves.

Comment: Yep, `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,` or remove that line would solve the issue. But.. persistent connections can be useful. Any particular reason you enabled it?

Comment: exactly because it is useful :D. All was working without any error with MariaDB 10.1.xx only when I updated to 10.2.13 it started appearing. And actually I need 10.2.xx because it has support for json data type.

Comment: So.. you use sockets, steams? Long processes? Persistence has its use-cases but the connection pool is very efficient as well.

Comment: Either way, set it to false or [change the db config](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-maxscale-persistent-connections) to allow for more connections and restart the service. So unless you have more then 100 people on your website every second.. I recommend the first.

Comment: I commented out persistent connection setting for now and will see how it goes.
I seen somewhere recommendation to uninstall php5-mysqlnd and install php5-mysqli and it should be sorted but there is nothing like that for php 7. Also want to check if charset can not be a problem.

Comment: You should probably also restart the server, because.. well the persistent connections are probably still open. The're persistent like that..

Comment: ahhh I see do you think charset can be causing it?
in connection settings charset is set to $charset = 'utf8';
but mysql server collation is : utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166589/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-igor-mizak).

Answer (score 0):

With error messages like that its hard to determine the exact cause of the issue. But one thing we do know, it fails to connect.

The most likely reason for that is that its out of usable connections and in combination with PHP it is usually caused by persistent connections.

Unlike normal connections, persistent connections *only* close when you close them. Useful for long processes so the server doesn't need to reconnect to the db every time so that you don't need to build in some sort of check if the database is still connected. This however means that you need to store the handle and close it yourself when it is finished to avoid over-exhausting the pool.

Normal connections are thrown back in to the connection pool when the script is finished executing. They still open (and closed if not used in a long time) and reused for the next request. As PHP is build on top of the HTTP protocol, which in most cases the request don't take more then a second to complete it makes little sense to use any persistence connections.

So unless you have a long process, maybe a socket server a persistent connection is use full.

So just disable it or remove the following line:

```
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
```

Or.. if still want to use persistent connections change the DB [configuration](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-maxscale-persistent-connections) to allow for more connection but this would most likely prolong the time before the issue pops back up again.